# Dropdown option "change" not working if change event is unbound and then rebound

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-mobile

I'm facing this weird issue with `off()` and `on()` event binding to a `select` dropdown:

If I unbind and then rebind the `change` event to the `select` dropdown I won't be able to change the dropdown shown value. In other words, the selected value is not updated properly in the dropdown, even if the change event is triggered.

If I remove the `off()` part, leaving only the event bounding with `on()`, everything works fine but obviously I'm not able to prevent the binding of the same event more than once.

See a live example here http://jsfiddle.net/z7o11exs/

Test case:

1. use the dropdown (it works! the selected value is correctly show in the dropdown)
2. refresh page. click on the first button **(off/on)** and then use the dropdown. It does not work properly as the selected value does not change
3. refresh page. click on the second button **(only on)** and then use the dropdown. It does work as expected. side effect: clicking *n* times on the 2nd button bounds *n* times the change event to the dropdown element

Here's the code:

```
//--- This binds the event to the element
function bindEvent(){
   $("#myselect").on("change", function(){
        console.log("change"); 
    });
}

//--- remove any change event previously added, then rebind it
function rebindEvent(){
    $("#myselect").off("change").on("change", function(){
        console.log("change"); 
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: works fine in fiddle.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar which browser are you using? I've only tested it against Chrome

Comment: i am using chrome only. logs in console for both button clicks.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar yes, the log is working but the dropdown UI is not updating with the selected value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [namespacing](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/):

```
//--- This binds the event to the element
function bindEvent(){
   $("#myselect").on("change.something", function(){
        console.log("change"); 
    });
}

//--- remove any change event previously added, then rebind it
function rebindEvent(){
    $("#myselect").off("change.something").on("change", function(){
        console.log("change"); 
    });
}
```

As @Karl said, using namespace is to:

Giving a name to your event allow you to identify that event. So when using .off, you can target a specific event to turn off.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get what I have to use instead of `something` in my example

Comment: @BeNdErR You can replace it by anything. It's a *name*

Comment: thank you, it works. Anyway I don't understand why.. can you enlighten me? Do I also have to use the namespace in the 1st button on() ? or just in the off() method?

Comment: yes, you need to use on first button also so later you off that namespaced event...

Comment: @BeNdErR both. Basicaly, jQuery UI bind its own event on change to update the displayed value. When using `.off`, you turn off the event you bind, but also the one jQuery UI did bind. Giving a name to your event allow you to identify that event. So when using `.off`, you can target a specific event to turn off. That way, jQuery UI event remain untouched.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon oh ok, now it's clear. I was not aware of the namespaces in jqm. thank you! I think you (or the answer owner) should edit the answer adding your explaination to make it more complete.

Comment: @BeNdErR I'll let him the honour so he can put ti in his own words

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `.selectmenu("refresh")` when you remove `change` binding. Because by default, `change` is attached to selectmenu as mentioned [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/js/widgets/forms/select.js#L147-L150). So if you remove it, you interrupt jQuery Mobile widget from "refreshing" to visually display the value.

See it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z7o11exs/2/).

```
function rebindEvent(){
    $("#myselect").off("change").on("change", function(){
        $(this).selectmenu("refresh");
    });
}
```